# Ubuntu can't find onboard bluetooth hardware

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I have a [MPG Z690 FORCE WIFI](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z690-FORCE-WIFI) motherboard that comes with an onboard bluetooth. I used to have Kubuntu and used the bluetooth but switched to Ubuntu recently and it can't even find the hardware. In the settings, even the toggle switch is disabled.

Some commands and their outputs:

`lspci -knn | grep New -A4`
[lspci output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efdxi.png)

`bluetoothd -dn`
[bluetoothd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bd35.png)

Here is the output of `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

```
[General]

# Default adaper name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
#PairableTimeout = 0

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels. Default is 60.
#AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
#NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
#DebugKeys = false

# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual

# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
#MultiProfile = off

# Permanently enables the Fast Connectable setting for adapters that
# support it. When enabled other devices can connect faster to us,
# however the tradeoff is increased power consumptions. This feature
# will fully work only on kernel version 4.1 and newer. Defaults to
# 'false'.
#FastConnectable = false

[Policy]

# The ReconnectUUIDs defines the set of remote services that should try
# to be reconnected to in case of a link loss (link supervision
# timeout). The policy plugin should contain a sane set of values by
# default, but this list can be overridden here. By setting the list to
# empty the reconnection feature gets disabled.
#ReconnectUUIDs=00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link
# lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
#ReconnectAttempts=7

# ReconnectIntervals define the set of intervals in seconds to use in between
# attempts.
# If the number of attempts defined in ReconnectAttempts is bigger than the
# set of intervals the last interval is repeated until the last attempt.
#ReconnectIntervals=1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64

# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
AutoEnable=true
```

The whole output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4668 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab9 (rev 11)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abb (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2805 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bd (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
05:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
```

The output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0db0:005a Micro Star International USB Audio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1462:7d30 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04d9:0007 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Pi400KB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Show us the *full* `lspci` output, because what you showed us is only your wifi, we have no evidence you have a bluetooth card.

Comment: @ThomasWard Just added but there isn't any.

Comment: What results for `lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 The bluetooth module is the onboard one not usb adapter. It won't show up anywhere. Note that I'VE USED IT IN KUBUNTU but I can't on Ubuntu.

Comment: Even internal Bluetooth normally show up on the USB bus, I think Broadcom has some that use SDIO but you have Intel wifi and the bluetooth is likely part of that device

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the useful information. The output of `lsusb` has been added.

Comment: Check BIOS settings to see if Bluetooth is still enabled.  Might have to disable in BIOS, boot, then go back into BIOS and enable

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks man! That did the job! Appreciate it!